# cookie is not expiring in jQuery

Tags: jquery, cookies

I'm an absolute new to jQuery.

i have to show popup to user only for two days.
(i.e, User-Guide)
using cookie we can validate this situation Right!

So, "Where i have to set cookie?"

my Code is :

```
        var eTime = new Date();
        eTime.setTime(eTime.getTime() + (30 * 1000));   
        //cookie will expire in 30 sec.
        $.cookie('guide', '1', {  expires : eTime});

        if($.cookie('guide') == '1'){                               

            alert("is Live");               
            $("#user-guide").fadeIn(3000);
        }
```

**Note** : for testing purpose i have changed cookie expire time to 30 sec.

**What I Think** : every time when page loaded cookie will setted with same value.

**I Tried This** : Setting cookie in login page (i.e, Call once) and check cookie status in home page.
***"And Its working fine"***, but it will also initial cookie when user login.

So, "Where i have to set cookie?"

Or other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to get this to work is create a `setCookie` function which does the cookie handling.

Your code looks fine but you always reset the cookie even when the cookie already exists.

You have to check the cookie first:

```
function setCookie() {
    var eTime = new Date();
    eTime.setTime(eTime.getTime() + (30 * 1000));   

    if($.cookie('guide') === null) {                               
       //create cookie which will expire in 30 sec.
       $.cookie('guide', '1', {  expires : eTime});
    } else {
       alert("is Live");               
       $("#user-guide").fadeIn(3000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
Its really help-full #Mivaweb.
But, what if i have to show popup for two times?

Comment: your popup will now be shown every time after the first time untill the cookie has expired. Or do you want to stop showing it after 2 times even if the cookie is not expired?

Comment: sorry for inconveniency,
actually i want to show popup to user only for two times.
so, i changed cookie expire time [$.cookie('guide', '1', {  expires : 365 * 10});].
as per your code popup will shown for only one time.